# product not inserting in mysql using a php webservive

Tags: php, mysql

I have  database where I have to insert a row but first I have to perform a check on pid. I am unable to found the solution kindly help.
Here is my php code:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    //$name = $_POST['name'];
    //$price = $_POST['price'];
    //$description = $_POST['description'];

$name = "zone";
$price = 123;
$description = "what";
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("IF ((select count(*) from products where pid = 7)= 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name',
'$price', '$description');
END
ELSE
BEGIN
END");


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Here is my android code

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));

            JSONObject jsonObject= new org.test.JSONParser().makeHttpRequest(URL, "POST", params);

            try {
                int success = jsonObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product

                   Log.d("create","created");
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("exc","exc "+e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(String file_url){
            pDialog.dismiss();
```

Product is not inserted and I get the message success 0 oops and error occurred that is $result is not 1.
Please help!

Comment: Check `mysql_error()` after your query to check for any MySQL errors.

Comment: I am getting this 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((select count(*) from products where pid = 7)= 0)

Comment: I have used altered IF statement as "== 0" instead of "=0" but still it gives me the same error

Comment: @user2370060, have you ever actually been successful in sending a statement like that via `mysql_query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't fully verify it, I'm pretty confident that sending MySQL an entire statement like that is going to fail miserably. However, if you break it into more realistic chunks it will succeed. Maybe something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `pid` FROM `products` WHERE `pid` = 7");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rows == 0) {
    // this means there is NOT a record WHERE pid = 7...
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description)
        VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");
    if ($result) {
        // an ERROR occurred INSERT'ing the data
    }
}
else {
    // this means there is a record WHERE pid = 7...
}
```

## EDIT

Your comment verified my assumptions about the failure since you said it produced this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ((select count(*) from products where pid = 7)= 0)

## SECURITY NOTE

Please move away from `mysql_query` and at least leverage [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and parameterized queries to ensure you're protected from SQL injection.